# CSS Changes Not Reflecting in Rails 7.1.2 Application Without Precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets

I have a new out of the box rails 7.1.2 app and my scss changes aren't visible without assets:precompile. If I precompile, everything works so links and files are set up correctly, but real-time updates are not happening as expected.

Environment:

Rails Version: 7.1.2
Ruby Version: ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-linux]
Operating System: ubuntu
my development.rb has:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.cache_store = :null_store
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.cache_classes = false
```

Stuff I've done:

- Ensured config.assets.debug and config.assets.compile are set to true.
- Caching is disabled in the development environment.
- Tried clearing browser cache and using incognito mode.
- Restarted Rails server multiple times.
- Checked for syntax errors in the SCSS file.
- Ensured that the listen gem is included and functioning.

No relevant errors are noted in the Rails log when changes are made to the SCSS file.
I'm looking for any suggestions or insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Is there a specific configuration or setup step that I might be missing for Rails 7.1.2? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Webpacker?

Comment: remove precompiled assets `bin/rails assets:clobber` and then run `bin/dev`

Comment: ah -- i'm confused -- i was trying to use cssbundling-rails -- let me look at this carefully and figure out the right strategy.

Comment: `webpacker` is obsolete. if you're using `cssbundling-rails` you need to run `bin/dev` to compile scss to css which then gets picked up by rails.

Comment: you don't need to run yarn build:css --watch then?

Comment: you do. which is what `bin/dev` does. it just runs `foreman` that runs rails server and build:css and whatever other commands you have in `Procfile.dev`